# How to create a custom auto generated ID number for a primary key column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created this table and I inserted the following values:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
     ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     Product_No AS RIGHT ('PDT0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)),10) PERSISTED,
     Product_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Product(Product_Name)
VALUES('Fish'), ('Shrimp'), ('Crab')
```

Then by using

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product
```

I get the following results:

```
ID  Product_No  Product_Name
1   PDT00001    Fish
2   PDT00002    Shrimp
3   PDT00003    Crab
```

As you can see that ID is the primary key column .. not Product_No ... I want `Product_No` to be the primary key column here without requiring to create ID column. Therefore, this is the output I want to get with

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product     (with Product_No as the Primary Key):

Product_No  Product_Name
-------------------------
PDT00001    Fish
PDT00002    Shrimp
PDT00003    Crab
```

So this is what I have tried:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
     Product_No INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY ('PDT0000' + Product_No AS VARCHAR(10)),10),
     Product_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

This is the following error I got:

> Incorrect syntax near 'PDT0000'.

So, how do I fix this ?

It would be really helpful if the appropriate syntax solution is provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to make `Product_No` the primary key - just use this SQL syntax:

```
CREATE TABLE Product
(
     ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
          CONSTRAINT UC_Product_ID UNIQUE,
     Product_No AS RIGHT ('PDT0000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(10)), 10) PERSISTED 
          CONSTRAINT PK_Product PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
     Product_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Now your column `Product_No` **is** the **primary key** for this table. You **cannot** combine the `IDENTITY` value column with the computed column specification into a single column - that's just not possible.

HOWEVER: even with this, and your sample data, this query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Product
```

still returns this result:

```
ID  Product_No  Product_Name
------------------------------
1   PDT00001    Fish
2   PDT00002    Shrimp
3   PDT00003    Crab
```

But what is *wrong* with that output?? I don't quite understand why this is a problem in your case?

If you don't want (or create for) the `ID` column, just run this query:

```
SELECT Product_No, Product_Name
FROM Product
```

to get this result:

```
Product_No  Product_Name
------------------------------
PDT00001    Fish
PDT00002    Shrimp
PDT00003    Crab
```

Comment: . I think the `identity` column should still be declared `unique`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff: yes, good point. Updated my response (and also took the opportunity to give the primary key constraint an explicit name)

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you want product_no to not have gap in it. As you know when a transaction gets rollback, identity value jumps over that value. Therefore, if you want that Product_no to be sequential do NOT‌ use identity. 
In addition having an extra column (ID) without any further use is annoying. 
In SQL‌ Server 2017 afterward the concept of sequential has been introduced and you can make use of that. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: `SEQUENCE` was actually introduced with SQL Server **2012** already (not 2017) .... and the `SEQUENCE` object has the same issues with numbers being skipped as the `IDENTITY` has - depending on your configuration

Answer (score 0):

> I want Product_No to be the primary key column here without requiring
>   to create ID column.

Using a sequence you can eliminate the need to have the ID column.  EG

```
--drop table if exists Product
--drop sequence seq_Product
go

create sequence seq_Product
start with 1
increment by 1 

go

CREATE TABLE Product
(
     Product_No varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY 
        default 'PDT' + format((next value for seq_Product),'00000' ),
     Product_Name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
)

insert into Product(Product_Name)
values ('Fish'),('Shrimp'),('Crab')



select * from Product
```