# MySQL Custom Id generation

Tags: mysql

I want to autogenerate sequence for a primary key field as a custom Id with auto-increment properties. For example, Id list should be like [P001, P002, P003...]. How can I generate this from normal Id column or otherwise?

```
CREATE TABLE `product` (
  `id` integer NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `name` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL
};
```

I have checked and found out solutions to do so in SQL. But I need to know the MySQL workaround for this.

My situation is similar to this question, but it doesn't work on MySQL.
[How to create a custom auto generated ID number for a primary key column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693101/how-to-create-a-custom-auto-generated-id-number-for-a-primary-key-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a TRIGGER.
Check out this question/answer [How to make MySQL table primary key auto increment with some prefix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893988/how-to-make-mysql-table-primary-key-auto-increment-with-some-prefix)

Comment: If a question has already been asked on SO, then please do **not** answer the question again, but vote / flag the question as duplicate.

Comment: @Shadow I appreciate that, still learning the ropes on SO.